# I want to show the post under the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://77.104.146.223/~thewhi58/

Open site click on image any image there is a title at the bottom

I want it to display the post under it its a excerpt

Code: http://pastebin.com/AdshznDN

Answer (score 0):

This text at bottom of images in lightbox is usualy TITLE added to A tag. Change text there.